# How do I treat generics?

Tags: rust

I would like to calculate a factorial using generics, but I get an error in `main`.

My full code:

```
pub trait Body {
    fn new() -> Self;

    fn fact(&self, x: usize) -> usize {
        match x {
            1 => 1,
            _ => x * self.fact(x - 1),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct RecursiveCall<T: Body> {
    level: usize,
    indicator: String,
    n_repeat: usize,
    body: T,
}

impl<T> RecursiveCall<T>
    where T: Body
{
    fn new(n_repeat: usize) -> RecursiveCall<T> {
        RecursiveCall {
            level: 0,
            indicator: "- ".to_string(),
            n_repeat: n_repeat,
            body: <T as Body>::new(),
        }
    }

    fn pre_trace(&self, fname: &str, arg: &usize) {
        let args: String = arg.to_string();
        println!("{}",
                 (vec![self.indicator.as_str(); self.level]).join("") +
                 self.level.to_string().as_str() + ":" + fname + "(" +
                 args.as_str() + ")");
    }

    fn post_trace(&self, fname: &str, arg: &usize, ret: &usize) {
        println!("{}",
                 (vec![self.indicator.as_str(); self.level]).join("") +
                 self.level.to_string().as_str() + ":" + fname + "=" +
                 ret.to_string().as_str());
    }

    fn print_trace(&mut self) {
        &self.pre_trace("fact", &self.n_repeat);
        self.level += 1;
        let ret = &self.body.fact(self.n_repeat);
        self.level -= 1;
        &self.post_trace("fact", &self.n_repeat, ret);

        println!("Difference={}", &ret.to_string().as_str());
    }
}

type B = Body;
fn main() {
    let t = RecursiveCall::<B>::new();
}
```

This error occurs in `main()`:

```
error: no associated item named `new` found for type `RecursiveCall<Body + 'static>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:61:13
   |
61 |     let t = RecursiveCall::<B>::new();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `new` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `Body : std::marker::Sized`, `Body : Body`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following traits define an item `new`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
   = help: candidate #1: `Body`
   = help: candidate #2: `std::sys_common::thread_info::NewThread`
   = help: candidate #3: `std::iter::ZipImpl`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Body + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:61:13
   |
61 |     let t = RecursiveCall::<B>::new();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Body + 'static`
   |
   = note: `Body + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required by `RecursiveCall`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Body + 'static: Body` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:61:13
   |
61 |     let t = RecursiveCall::<B>::new();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Body` is not implemented for `Body + 'static`
   |
   = note: required by `RecursiveCall`

error[E0038]: the trait `Body` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:61:13
   |
61 |     let t = RecursiveCall::<B>::new();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Body` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: method `new` has no receiver
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to the answer is in this note from the compiler:

> note: the method `new` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `Body : std::marker::Sized`, `Body : Body`

You've defined `B` as a type alias for `Body`, so the names `B` and `Body` both mean the same thing in your program (at least in this module).

When you define a trait, the compiler also defines a type with the same name. However, that type cannot be instantiated directly (unlike a class in C++/C#/Java/etc.). Yet, that's exactly what you're trying to do!

The trait bound `Body : std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied because `Body`, being the type defined by the compiler corresponding to the trait of the same name, is an unsized type. Unsized types can only be used in pointers and references (e.g. `&Body`, `Box<Body>`, etc.).

The trait bound `Body : Body` is not satisfied because your trait is not [object-safe](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/). It's not object-safe because the method `new` doesn't have a `self` parameter (this is what the compiler means in the last note: `` method `new` has no receiver ``).

Normally, you would define a struct or an enum and implement the trait for that type, and then use that type when instantiating `RecursiveCall`. Try replacing `type B = Body;` with the following:

```
struct B;

impl Body for B {
    fn new() -> B {
        B
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem by your help!
Thank you for your kindness.